# How to present a semi-transparent (half-cut) viewcontroller in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

in iOS 7 there is no problem for this method:

```
_rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[_rootViewController presentViewController:self animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But in iOS 8 it did nothing.How to solve it? Is it a Bug for iOS 8？

Answer (score 13):

My answer is more simple, below code. This works in iOS8 (XCode6 GM seed).

```
HogeViewController *vc = [[HogeViewController alloc] init];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: if you rotation your app in the vc view what happened? In my app it rotate when the method - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

Comment: Beware. If you are using an unwind segue, you may need to explicitly call dismissViewController in your unwind segue handler to make the view disappear.

Answer (score 3):

> Note this workaround was needed on xcode6_beta7. The lastest xcode6
>   has the UIModalPresentationOver* styles fixed. So, I'm just assigning them to myModalViewController.modalPresentationStyle and now it works ok.

Finally made it work in iOS 8 after reading the [UIPresentationController help](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPresentationController/shouldRemovePresentersView) and [this post](http://dativestudios.com/blog/2014/06/29/presentation-controllers/)

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
MyModalController *myModalController = [[MyModalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyModalController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myModalController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
navController.transitioningDelegate = myModalController;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can make the modal view controller inherit from UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

```
@interface MyModalController : UIViewController <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
```

and override presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:...

```
-(UIPresentationController *)presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceViewController:(UIViewController *)source
{
    if (presented == self) {
        return [[TransparentPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:presented presentingViewController:presenting];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

returning an instance of TransparentPresentationController which inherits from UIPresentationController

```
@interface TransparentPresentationController : UIPresentationController
```

and overrides shouldRemovePresentersView

```
- (BOOL) shouldRemovePresentersView {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I write this in another sence:

Comment: I write this in two scenes: In ViewController: - (IBAction)present:(id)sender {
    //scene two
    SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; [controller present];
}
For sence two:-(void)present
{
    UIViewController *root = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [self setTransitioningDelegate:self.transitionController];
    self.modalPresentationStyle= UIModalPresentationCustom;
    [root presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];

}
But it did not do the delegate method.Why?yours is right.

Comment: I overrode shouldRemovePresentersView to return NO.  But I still cannot access the presenters view.  the viewForKey returns nil